# When should I use raw pointers over smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, smart-pointers

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585247/code-reading-where-can-i-read-great-modern-and-well-documented-c-code/2585397#2585397), it looks like it is a best practice to use [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) as much as possible, and to reduce the usage of "normal"/raw pointers to minimum.

Is that true?

Comment: Just for the record, many smart pointer types *are* just as fast as raw pointers. It's just that when you say "smart pointer", nearly everyone *hears* it as "shared pointer", and shared pointers are much slower than raw pointers. But `scoped_ptr` or  `unique_ptr` have no performance overhead. So "I want performance" isn't really a valid excuse for avoiding smart pointers. Just for avoiding `shared_ptr` specifcially

Answer (score 117, accepted):

No, it's not true. If a function needs a pointer and has nothing to do with ownership, then I strongly believe that a regular pointer should be passed for the following reasons:

- No ownership, therefore you don't know what kind of a smart pointer to pass
- If you pass a specific pointer, like `shared_ptr`, then you won't be able to pass, say, `scoped_ptr`

The rule would be this - if you know that an entity must take a certain kind of ownership of the object, ***always*** use smart pointers - the one that gives you the kind of ownership you need. If there is no notion of ownership, ***never*** use smart pointers.

Example1:

```
void PrintObject(shared_ptr<const Object> po) //bad
{
    if(po)
      po->Print();
    else
      log_error();
}

void PrintObject(const Object* po) //good
{
    if(po)
      po->Print();
    else
      log_error();
}
```

Example2:

```
Object* createObject() //bad
{
    return new Object;
}

some_smart_ptr<Object> createObject() //good
{
   return some_smart_ptr<Object>(new Object);
}
```

Comment: An alternative in Example1 is to pass a reference as no ownership is transferred - as in the old `auto_ptr`.

Comment: I love the note about ownership (which is what smart pointers are all about). However, you may want to consider that PrintObject should take a const& instead of a const*. That way, you're guaranteed not to be able to transfer ownership, so there's no question of whether PrintObject should take possession of it or not.

Comment: @DanS: passing an auto_ptr would be simply wrong - it would destroy the object after function completion

Comment: @Nicol: Indeed, I will edit my answer in order to make pointer necessary :)

Comment: @Armen: Yes, but to avoid transfer of ownership you pass a reference. It made sense to me when I wrote it but on reflection is less than clear.

Comment: I think it should say "void PrintObject(const Object* const po)", otherwise you don't guarantee that the pointer won't be change to another address inside the function.

Comment: @AudioDroid: I don't like top level consts on my function parameters. Even if the pointer did change to point to another address the original pointer passed would remain unaltered

Comment: I agree that the parameter should be passed by reference if at all possible. I would suggest a raw pointer only be used if the function must not assume ownership **and** the object is optional so the pointer may need to be NULL.

Comment: Note that this answer applies equally well to class members, and not just to function parameters.  If the class member implies ownership, smart pointers **may**  be an appropriate solution; if the class member is strictly for navigation, raw pointers are more appropriate.  (Also note that if you're using an OO paradigm, the only "owner" is often the class itself, and there's no way `this` can be made to be a smart pointer.)

Comment: @James: I totally agree with you except the part where you say there's no way `this` can be made to be a smart pointer. It can, by means of `boost::make_shared_from_this`

Comment: @Armen The type of `this` is specified by the standard, and it is not a smart pointer type.  `boost::make_shared_from_this` provides a mechanism for safely creating a `boost::shared_ptr` from `this`, but it doesn't change the type of `this` itself.  (IIRC, it does make the object share in ownership.)  There are also invasive pointers (including in `boost`) which permit safely creating smart pointers from `this`.

Comment: @Armen: Wow. I didn't know that the original pointer would remain unaltered, I just tried it (just added "po = 0;" in the function). Leaves me puzzled. I will try to find out more about that.

Comment: @Audio: Well of course it wouldn't - you pass the pointer BY VALUE (i.e. you copy it). The behavior you expect would be if you passed a reference to a pointer as in `const Object*& po`

Comment: @AudioDroid to prevent the pointer from changing to another address you need `Object *const`, not `const Object* `.

Comment: @Martinho: The thing is that he thought that without the top-level const the passed parameter could be changed as well :)

Comment: Better : `void PrintObject(const Object &po)`

Comment: @Roddy, not if a null object may be passed

Comment: @Armen: well, yes. :) Personally I prefer to avoid functions that can take NULLs in C++, but maybe that's just me...

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: If a null object can be passed, you also could use `boost::optional`, as in `void PrintObject(boost::optional<Object const&> var = boost::optional<Object const&>());`

Answer (score 19):

Using smart pointers to manage ownership is the right thing to do.
Conversely, using raw pointers wherever ownership is *not* an issue is **not** wrong.

Here are some perfectly legitimate use of raw pointers (remember, it is always assumed they are non-owning):

where they compete with references

- argument passing; but references can't be null, so are preferable
- as class members to denote association rather than composition; usually preferable to references because the semantics of assignment are more straightforward and in addition an invariant set up by the constructors can ensure that they are not `0` for the lifetime of the object
- as a handle to a (possibly polymorphic) object owned somewhere else; references can't be null so again they are preferable
- `std::bind` uses a convention where arguments that are passed are copied into the resulting functor; however `std::bind(&T::some_member, this, ...)` only makes a copy of the pointer whereas `std::bind(&T::some_member, *this, ...)` copies the object; `std::bind(&T::some_member, std::ref(*this), ...)` is an alternative

where they do **not** compete with references

- as iterators!
- argument passing of **optional** parameters; here they compete with `boost::optional<T&>`
- as a handle to a (possibly polymorphic) object owned somewhere else, when they can't be declared at the site of initialization; again, competing with `boost::optional<T&>`

As a reminder, it's almost always wrong to write a function (that is not a constructor, or a function member that e.g. takes ownership) that accepts a smart pointer unless it in turn pass it to a constructor (e.g. it's correct for `std::async` because semantically it's close to being a call to the `std::thread` constructor). If it's synchronous, no need for the smart pointer.

---

To recap, here's a snippet that demonstrates several of the above uses. We're writing and using a class that applies a functor to every element of an `std::vector<int>` while writing some output.

```
class apply_and_log {
public:
    // C++03 exception: it's acceptable to pass by pointer to const
    // to avoid apply_and_log(std::cout, std::vector<int>())
    // notice that our pointer would be left dangling after call to constructor
    // this still adds a requirement on the caller that v != 0 or that we throw on 0
    apply_and_log(std::ostream& os, std::vector<int> const* v)
        : log(&os)
        , data(v)
    {}

    // C++0x alternative
    // also usable for C++03 with requirement on v
    apply_and_log(std::ostream& os, std::vector<int> const& v)
        : log(&os)
        , data(&v)
    {}
    // now apply_and_log(std::cout, std::vector<int> {}) is invalid in C++0x
    // && is also acceptable instead of const&&
    apply_and_log(std::ostream& os, std::vector<int> const&&) = delete;

    // Notice that without effort copy (also move), assignment and destruction
    // are correct.
    // Class invariants: member pointers are never 0.
    // Requirements on construction: the passed stream and vector must outlive *this

    typedef std::function<void(std::vector<int> const&)> callback_type;

    // optional callback
    // alternative: boost::optional<callback_type&>
    void
    do_work(callback_type* callback)
    {
        // for convenience
        auto& v = *data;

        // using raw pointers as iterators
        int* begin = &v[0];
        int* end = begin + v.size();
        // ...

        if(callback) {
            callback(v);
        }
    }

private:
    // association: we use a pointer
    // notice that the type is polymorphic and non-copyable,
    // so composition is not a reasonable option
    std::ostream* log;

    // association: we use a pointer to const
    // contrived example for the constructors
    std::vector<int> const* data;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Few cases, where you may want to use pointers:

- Function pointers (obviously no smart pointer)
- Defining your own smart pointer or container
- Dealing with low level programming, where raw pointers are crucial
- Decaying from raw arrays

Comment: Though you can use containers instead of arrays, or smart arrays. Also, why does low-level programming necessitate raw pointers (there are perhaps places, but you did not specify on them)?

Comment: There is something similar to a smart pointer for functions: `boost::function` or `std::function`.  Those are wrappers that handle copying, etc., for various kinds of function objects, function pointers, etc.

Answer (score 4):

One instance where reference counting (used by shared_ptr in particular) will break down is when you create a cycle out of the pointers (e.g. A points to B, B points to A, or A->B->C->A,  or etc).  In that case, none of the objects will ever be automatically freed, because they are all keeping each other's reference counts greater than zero.

For that reason, whenever I am creating objects that have a parent-child relationship (e.g. a tree of objects), I will use shared_ptrs in the parent objects to hold their child objects, but if the child objects need a pointer back to their parent, I will use a plain C/C++ pointer for that.

Comment: Good point, but still that's what weak pointers are for, like `boost::weak_ptr`

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgotten about weak_ptr.

Answer (score 4):

The use of smart pointers is always recommended because they clearly document the ownership.

What we really miss, however, is a "blank" smart pointer, one that does not imply any notion of ownership.

```
template <typename T>
class ptr // thanks to Martinho for the name suggestion :)
{
public:
  ptr(T* p): _p(p) {}
  template <typename U> ptr(U* p): _p(p) {}
  template <typename SP> ptr(SP const& sp): _p(sp.get()) {}

  T& operator*() const { assert(_p); return *_p; }
  T* operator->() const { assert(_p); return _p; }

private:
  T* _p;
}; // class ptr<T>
```

This is, indeed, the simplest version of any smart pointer that may exist: a type that documents that it does not own the resource it points too.

Comment: I don't see how this is a "smart" pointer. It is a wrapper around a raw pointer that neither shares ownership nor can detect when the pointed-to object has been deleted. What advantage does it offer over a simple raw pointer?

Comment: @OrbWeaver: functionally ? none. Semantically, however, it makes it clear that ownership was considered, and that it was decided that the variable would **not** have ownership. When you see a method `void foo(Bar*)` it is always ambiguous whether or not the method takes ownership of the pointer or not, if you see `void foo(client_ptr<Bar>)` then you *know* that it does not take ownership -- though I would be interested in a better name :)

Comment: Oh I see. Interesting technique, I'd never have thought of using a class in that way.

Comment: Funny names: `not_so_smart_ptr<T>`, `stupid_ptr<T>`, `sep_ptr<T>`. On a serious note, I think just `ptr<T>` is ok.

Comment: Sounds more like a `pointless_ptr<T>` to me. A smart pointer *guarantees* that ownership follows the indicated semantics. This one guarantees nothing, it just indicates that "someone, somewhere, thought that this shouldn't have ownership". Exactly like a raw pointer does. It makes no gaurantee that the program will actually *behave* like that.

Comment: This is not a smart pointer. It's a safer pointer class that checks for pointer validity before use. It's something like a weak_ptr that doesn't interact with a  shared_ptr. Not pointless, not smart, more like a safer-than-raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think a little bit more thorough answer was given here: [Which kind of pointer do I use when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when)

Excerpted from that link: "Use dumb pointers (raw pointers) or references for **non-owning references** to resources and when you know that the **resource will outlive** the referencing object / scope." (bold preserved from the original)

The problem is that if you're writing code for general use it's not always easy to be absolutely certain the object will outlive the raw pointer. Consider this example:

```
struct employee_t {
    employee_t(const std::string& first_name, const std::string& last_name) : m_first_name(first_name), m_last_name(last_name) {}
    std::string m_first_name;
    std::string m_last_name;
};

void replace_current_employees_with(const employee_t* p_new_employee, std::list<employee_t>& employee_list) {
    employee_list.clear();
    employee_list.push_back(*p_new_employee);
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::list<employee_t> current_employee_list;
    current_employee_list.push_back(employee_t("John", "Smith"));
    current_employee_list.push_back(employee_t("Julie", "Jones"));
    employee_t* p_person_who_convinces_boss_to_rehire_him = &(current_employee_list.front());

    replace_current_employees_with(p_person_who_convinces_boss_to_rehire_him, current_employee_list);
}
```

Much to its surprise, the `replace_current_employees_with()` function can inadvertently cause one of its parameters to be deallocated before it's finished using it.

So even though it might at first seem like the `replace_current_employees_with()` function doesn't need ownership of it's parameters, it needs some kind of defense against the possiblity of its parameters being insidiously deallocated before it's finished using them. The simplest solution is to actually take (temporary shared) ownership of the parameter(s), presumably through a `shared_ptr`.

But if you really don't want to take ownership, there is now a safe option - and this is the shameless plug portion of the answer - "[registered pointers](http://duneroadrunner.github.io/SaferCPlusPlus/#registered-pointers)". "registered pointers" are smart pointers that behave like raw pointers, except that they are (automatically) set to `null_ptr` when the target object is destroyed, and by default, will throw an exception if you try to access an object that has already been deleted.

Also note that registered pointers can be "disabled" (automatically replaced with their raw pointer counterpart) with a compile-time directive, allowing them to be used (and incur overhead) in debug/test/beta modes only. So you should really have to resort actual raw pointers quite rarely.

Answer (score -6):

It is true. I can not see the benefits of raw pointers over smart pointers, especially in a complex project.

For tempory and lightweight usage, raw pointers are fine though.