# Does this code leak memory? (references, new, but no delete)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does using references instead of pointers, resolve memory leaks in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783939/does-using-references-instead-of-pointers-resolve-memory-leaks-in-c)

When I ask this question

[Does using references instead of pointers, resolve memory leaks in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783939/does-using-references-instead-of-pointers-resolve-memory-leaks-in-c)

A new question appears and I ask it in this post.

Does this code leak memory?

```
class my_class
{
  ...
};

my_class& func()
{
  my_class* c = new my_class;
  return *c;
}

int main()
{
  my_class& var1 = func();

  // I think there is no memory leak.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is the same code you just gave us. It is terrible. Do not use `new` (unless you have a **very** good reason).

Comment: from the linked post, first answer "You haven't resolved any memory leaks. If you new, then you must delete."

Comment: @Kerrek SB: sorry, but I disagree. Certainly objects on the stack are a very nice thing, but there are many legit reasons why `new` is a good idea. And there is a reason why many smart pointer classes exist that can exist on the stack and will automatically call `delete` on the kept instance when going out of scope. However, I agree that this code is terrible - among other things because of the ugly mix of reference and pointer.

Comment: I don't understand why you had to post this again. Every answer to your first question said you hadn't resolved any leaks by returning a reference.

Comment: @STATUS: Modern C++ has so many nice ways to construct managed objects (I'm thinking of you, `make_shared`) that there should be _very_ few reasons to physically write out a `new` expression. OK, maybe if you're implementing your own library function (like `make_unique`). I'm not saying "never"... just *really carefully* :-) For a novice, I'm willing to bet that there's always a better, more idiomatic solution than a naked `new`!

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is your friend if you still doubt us.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: fair enough. I was thinking of some uses where certain limitations apply. I suppose you are right for the more general cases. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does leak memory. Everything that was created by `new` has to be destroyed by `delete`. There's `new` in your code, but no `delete`. That immediately means that the `new`ed memory is leaked.

Comment: Not exactly. A smart pointer class (like: auto_ptr class) is a special case, it deletes memory automatically... so I hate it very much...

Comment: @Stan: Well, it deletes by using `delete`. From the core language point of view, `auto_ptr` is a user-defined type. There's not much difference in that respect between the situations when something is deleted implicitly by `auto_ptr` or explicitly by the user.

Answer (score 2):

It does create a memory leak. Look at this example:

```
int main()
{
  my_class var1;
  my_class& var2 = var1;
  ...
}
```

Here the destructor for var1 will only be called once, if your assumtions were true, it would be called twice.

Comment: Also, destructor being called by itself does not free the allocated memory. A call to `operator delete` needs to be made to do the actual freeing. Note that I'm not saying this needs to be done manually, the compiler does all this automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to free every instance of an object u allocated using the 'new' operator or using the 'malloc' function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clear the memory by using 'delete' when you are done.