# Declaring a reference to object and the assignment operator

Tags: c++, reference, assignment-operator

I feel like this question is basic enough to be out there somewhere, but I can't seem to be able to find an answer for it.

Suppose I have this code:

```
//class member function
std::map< std::string, std::string > myMap;

const std::map< std::string, std::string >& bar()
{
   return myMap;
}

void myFunc( std::map< std::string, std::string >& foo1 )
{
   foo1 = bar();
   std::map< std::string, std::string >& foo2 = bar();
}
```

My understanding is that if I start using foo2, since foo2 is a reference to the same instance as what bar() returns, anything I do with foo2 will be reflected in myMap. But what about foo1? Does foo1 get a copy of myMap or does it also point to the same instance as what bar() returns? The c++ standard library says that the assignment operator for std::map will copy the elements over, but then does that mean the assignment operator is not really invoked in the declaration of foo2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

References are not reseatable in C++. This means that once they're initialized, you can't reassign them. Instead, any assignment actually involve the referred object. So in your code,

```
foo1 = bar();
std::map< std::string, std::string >& foo2 = bar();
```

the first line calls `std::map::operator=` on the object that was passed as a parameter to `myFunc`. After that, `foo1` stills refers to that same object -- but its value (e.g. what elements it holds) may very well has been changed.

Note that the second line is *not* assignment if there ever was any doubt that it was in your mind. Instead, it is an initialization. Since the return type of bar is actually `std::map<std::string, std::string> const&`, it can't bind to `std::map<std::string, std::string>&` so it's a compile error.

---

To expand on the 'philosophical' side of things, C++ references are designed to be as transparent as possible and don't really exist as objects. This is using the C++ Standard meaning of the term (it is not related to OOP): it means that for instance reference types do *not* have a size. Instead, `sizeof(T&) == sizeof(T)`. Similarly, references do not have addresses and it's not possible to form a pointer or a reference to a reference: given `int& ref = i;`, then `&ref == &i`.

References are thus purposefully meant to be used *as if* the referred objects were being used themselves. The only thing reference-specific that happens in the lifetime of a reference is its initialization: what it can bind to and what it means in terms of lifetime.

Comment: +1 Thank you, I learned something new myself. I just made a test and I was indeed absolutely 100% WRONG and you are right =-)

Comment: Ok great! Thanks, what I really needed to know was that assignment operator is invoked in foo1 and is not being invoked in foo2. Great explanation, thanks!

Comment: @Luc If possible, can you go over why reference variables are generally not used? I have a better understanding of what they are (thanks to your answer) but it seems coders generally favor pointers over it. Is it the redundancy? The limited scope?

Comment: @MannyD My experience is not similar to yours. I use references and see references used as local variables regularly, and for this usage they are usually preferable over pointers.

Comment: @Luc I guess I should clarify. I see/use them all the time in function parameter lists but I don't see why you'd want to declare one within a body of code or even as a class member.

Comment: @MannyD That's what I meant by 'local variable'. There are several questions on the topic already, I suggest you look there for answers. Here's [something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675651/when-should-i-use-c-pointers-over-smart-pointers/6676183#6676183) I said on the topic (the question is originally about pointers vs smart pointers though). It's likely there also are people in the C++ chat willing to discuss this. (It's a more appropriate place for discussions than here.)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
foo1 = bar();
```

creates a copy (because that's what `map`'s assignment operator does).

Comment: seems strange to return a reference to a global variable, no?

Comment: @0A0D: Not really, it can be used for encapsulation, if the "global" variable doesn't actually have external linkage.  Or you might return a reference to either global variable `a` or global variable `b`.