# Managing an object with multiple pointers to it

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, memory-management

Let's say I have two abstract classes, `A1` and `A2`. `A1` has a function called `foo()`, `A2` has a function called `bar()`. I create many different child classes of these base classes, say `C1,C2,C3`,..., that may or may not inherit `A1` and/or `A2.` I now want to loop over all classes of type `A1` and all classes of type `A2` and call `foo()` resp `bar()`. My question is what is the best way to achieve this? My approach would be to use either smart pointers or vectors that hold instances of `C1,C2,...`, ie:

```
std::vector<C1> c1s;
std::vector<C2> c2s;
std::unique_ptr<C3> c3;
...
```

I then declare two integers, `n_A1` and `n_A2` that specify how many instances I have of each abstract class `A1` and `A2`. I then define two arrays of pointers:

```
A1 **a1s = new A1*[n_A1];
A2 **a2s = new A2*[n_A2];
```

and then manually add all the addresses of the instances to these arrays. For example, if `c1s` has length 2, `c2s` has length 3, and if `C1` inherits `A1`, `C2` inherits `A2`, `C3` inherits `A1` and `A2` I would do:

```
a1s[0]=&c1s[0];
a1s[1]=&c1s[1];
a2s[0]=&c2s[0];
a2s[1]=&c2s[1];
a2s[2]=&c2s[2];
a1s[2]=c3.get();
a2s[3]=c3.get();
```

So thus `n_A1=3` and `n_A2=4` and I can now loop over the arrays of addresses a1s and a2s and call the functions `foo()` or `bar()`. When deleting the instance holding all these objects, I just have to free the arrays `a1s` and `a2s`.

Being constantly recommended not to use raw pointers in C++, I wonder if this is a good way to solve this problem? Are there any risks with this approach? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Raw owning pointers are problematic, *"observer"* pointers are ok. So `std::vector<A1 *>a1s{&c1s[0], &c1s[0], c3.get()};` (Care have to be done for pointer validity though).

Comment: "not to use raw pointers" is an unfortunate myth. "using raw owning pointers" is the evil

Comment: Highly recommend to read: [When should I use raw pointers over smart pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6675651/580083). An exemplary quote from the accepted answer: _"If there is no notion of ownership, **never** use smart pointers."_

Comment: You can use the [observer pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184702/implementation-of-observer-pattern-in-c14)

Comment: Q: _"I now want to loop over all classes of type A1 and all classes of type A2 and call foo() resp bar()."_ What if a class is both an A1 and an A2? Do you call both foo() and bar()?

Comment: Also, you ask a lot of questions (I count four). Which one should we answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
class IA
{
   virtual ~IA();
}

class A1 :public  IA
{
   virtual ~A1();
   virtual void foo();
}

class A2 :public  IA
{
   virtual ~A2();
   virtual void bar();
}

class C1 :public  A1
{
   virtual ~C1();
   virtual void foo();
}
class C2 :public  A2
{
   virtual ~C2();
   virtual void bar();
}
class C3 :public A1,public A2
{
   virtual ~C3();
   virtual void foo();
   virtual void bar();
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<IA*> AllAsObjects;
  AllAsObjects.push_back(new C1());
  AllAsObjects.push_back(new C2());
  AllAsObjects.push_back(new C3());
  for (IA* Obj :AllAsObjects)
  {
    if(dynamic_cast<A1*>(Obj))
      dynamic_cast<A1*>(Obj)->foo();
    if(dynamic_cast<A2*>(Obj))
      dynamic_cast<A2*>(Obj)->bar();
  }
}
```

I think that is what you need

*be aware that is self compiled

Comment: `IA` class should have virtual destructor. And, it would be better to use a vector of `std::unique_ptr<IA>`.

Comment: his question was about using raw pointers so of course i am adding virtual destructor, but using `unique_ptr` would be off point i think
@DanielLangr